# Why is useQuery making my component re-render when I come back to the tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using react-query library, and I looked it up, and useQuery can make your react component re-render because it has states, but the weird thing is that it re-renders when I change tabs (like, I go to youtube, then come back to my app and the component just re-renders). But it only happens with useQuery, and I don't understand why.

Edit: It also happens when I click my console and then click the app again

The code is very simple:

```
const { data } = useQuery("pokemon", () =>
    axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
);
console.log(data);
```

It's literally happening right now. Every time I go back to my app, it just logs the data again. I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Are using the react-query library? @GusDev

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using react-query library

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using the [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) library, consider setting the [`refetchOnWindowFocus`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) option to `false`

So your code should look like this

```js
const { data } = useQuery("pokemon", () =>
    axios("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"), 
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    }
);
console.log(data);
```

You can also set a `refetchInterval` option in milliseconds to only refetch at certain time intervals

Comment: That indeed solved the problem, altho I have no clue why that happens, but thank you!

Comment: Great! Go ahead and upvote the answer as well. @GusDev